# City search form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I am trying to make a City Search field working but it does not work :(

In jsfiddle is working ok
    http://jsfiddle.net/babarazvan/uvdqbj9p/4/
But in my page does not.
It might be related to the other resources that i have in the page ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.noconflict.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.2.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Could yoou please help.

Comment: Can you show us your site, where you want to implement it?

Comment: It's very hard to say what could be wrong without any details. Are there errors in the browser's JS console?

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget the css?

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-hover,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-active {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: -1px;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:14px;
}
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
    background: white url("./ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
}
#city {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is there. I have found the issue. The page code is not working over htts, on http is working fine.